# Running the OSGi Equinox console on an hostile environment

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

Let's say I have this OSGI Equinox application and that I'd like to know bundles are loaded, as well as their state. To do that, I thought about running the console, but I am not sure how to do that.

The application has the following folder structure:

```
workspace/
config/
features/
bundles/
```

The `config/` directory contains both a config.ini file as well as error log files and some folders named with plugins' symbolic names.

I've tried running from the main(home) folder

```
java -jar bundles/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar -console -consoleLog
```

but all I get is a

> osgi> !SESSION 2013-06-04 08:57:53.023
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.7.0_17 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -console -consoleLog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-06-04 08:57:53.512 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
>   acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
>   bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
>           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
>           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>           at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:150)

which raises the question of knowing where should the `config.ini` file be. As stated, I know there's one at `config/`, and while I know this RCP application uses that file as its config file, I am not too sure the same can be said of the console I've launched. Why? Because I've added the following line to `bundles/config.ini` no avail:

```
osgi.bundles=\
org.eclipse.core.runtime@5:start \
org.bountycastle@3:start, \
org.jdom@3:start, \
org.eclipse.equinox.event@3:start, \
org.eclipse.update.configurator@2:start, \
org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, \
org.eclipse.equinox.ds@4:start, \
org.eclipse.equinox.util@4:start, \
org.eclipse.core.runtime@start


osgi.startLevel=10
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=5
```

Any cues are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the rest of the config.ini? I'm interested to see anything regarding the runlevels. Also, I'm interested in seeing the rest of the log.

Comment: I've edited the original post with extra information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with plain OSGi (and not with eclipse application) you should add the following to your config.ini:

```
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
osgi.noShutdown=true
```

Also, if you are not sure which config.ini is used, you may explicitly define the path by providing cmd arg:

```
java -jar .... -configuration <location of config.ini>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rest of the config.ini, I see that you actually start org.eclipse.core.runtime twice: one time @5:start and one time with (again) runlevel 5 based on the default start level.

Can you try to remove the last org.eclipse.core.runtime@start and change the first to runlevel 1? (org.eclipse.core.runtime@1:start) (maybe runlevel 2 would also work).

This way, you make sure the core.runtime is started first.

Comment: I've tried but the problem still persists (exactly the same error message).